# C# comfortable way to construct byte array from different objects

Tags: c#, arrays, stream, mono, byte

I am looking for a way to fast and simple implementation of this paradigm:

```
MyByteArray mb = new MyByteArray();
mb.Add<byte>(bytevalue);
mb.Add<float>(floatvalue);
mb.Add<string>(str);
mb.Add<MyClass>(object);
```

And then get byte[] from mb to send it as a byte packet via RPC call (to be decoded on the other side using the same technique).

I've found MemoryStream, but it looks like too overheaded for this simple operation.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking for is [BinaryWritter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx). But it still needs a Stream to write on for pure logic reason. And the only Stream that fits in your need is MemoryStream.

Are you afraid of performance overhead ? You can create your MemoryStream from an existing byte array ;

```
    byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            binaryWriter.Write(1.2F); // float
            binaryWriter.Write(1.9D); // double
            binaryWriter.Write(1); // integer
            binaryWriter.Write("str"); // string
        }
    }
    // buffer is filled with your data now.
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the case for Protocol Buffers, you could look at at [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net).

First, let's decorate the classes.

```
[ProtoContract]
class User
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
class Message
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public byte Type { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public float Value { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(3)]
  public User Sender { get; set; }
}
```

Then we create our message.

```
var msg = new Message
{
  Type = 1,
  Value = 1.1f,
  Sender = new User
  {
    Id = 8,
    Name = "user"
  }
};
```

And now, we can use ProtoBuf's serializer to do all our work.

```
// memory
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
  Serializer.Serialize<Message>(mem, msg);
  var bytes = mem.GetBuffer();
}

// file
using (var file = File.Create("message.bin")) Serializer.Serialize<Message>(file, msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way to  achieve this is to use a combination of builtin class in .net

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Program  program   =  new Program(); 
            var listBytes  = new List<byte>();
               listBytes.Add( program.CastToBytes("test")); 
               listBytes.Add(program.CastToBytes(5));         
        }
```

**Note** 
for a custom object  you have to define an `implicit operator` on how the properties or all the object should be converted

```
        public byte[] CastToBytes<T>(T value)            
        {
            //this will cover most  of primitive types 

            if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            {
                return BitConverter.GetBytes((dynamic)value);
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((dynamic) value); 
            }
            //for a custom  object  you  have to  define  the rules 
            else
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, value);
                return  memoryStream.GetBuffer();     
            }                                    
        }

    }
```